# jquery, ajax, php, json - is there a good cascade/chained select plugin for jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, user-interface

Does anyone know for a good cascade/chained select jquery 1.4.x plugin(s) (or jquery ui widget) that uses ajax call to php that returns json format data for populating options?

Answer (score 0):

This question is vague, but you can use the .post() function to post requests to a PHP file and then have the PHP create an array and use `json_encode()` to encode the array into JSON and then echo that JSON data, which can be received by the jQuery .post(). Do something like this:

jQuery:

```
$.post("you_php_file.php",{ request: "YOUR_REQUEST" },function(data){
    //do something with the data, stored with the variable data
    $('ul li:nth-child(1)').html(data[0]);
    $('ul li:nth-child(2)').html(data[1]);
},"json")
```

PHP:

```
$request = $_POST['request'];
//create an array with the data you want to send to JavaScript
$array = array();
$array[] = 'Hello';
$array[] = 'World!';
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: I used this one (http://remysharp.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/09/select-chain.php) in one app but i was never satisfied with the eval function it uses and it is pretty old script (jquery 1.2.x) and..., i never liked it, but since i never had a time/knoledge to write my own... I don't need the code how to do it (thanks Jacob) but do you know if there is a really, really cool (read: GOOD) plugin/widget that someone already made?